# Is it a good idea to add cross references in conclusion

Tags: phd, journals, paper-submission, online-publication, conclusion-section

Is it a good idea to add **cross references** in Conclusion section of a research article?

For example, can we refer to results described in previous section of paper in the conclusion section?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @NateEldredge, Sir, added in the question

Comment: Seems to be pretty standard.

Comment: Yes....... ....

Comment: Are you asking about writing something like "We showed X (Section Y)"?

Comment: @ GoodDeeds, Sir, yes

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire It might be better to add such an example in the question then. I don't know the answer to your question, but such a style does not seem to be common (in my field), with the conclusion section referring to high level outcomes rather than specific parts of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your paper is quite long, that could be helpful.